# input to sql not ok with 'copy-paste'

Tags: php, sql, database, forms, copy-paste

i have a php form, that adds a 'review' to a 'guide' in an SQL database.
i finally figured out my problem, and it is when i use copy paste in the input areas.
what can cause this??
any help appreciated!!

this is the [link](http://www.mzungu.co.il/add_review.php)
this is my code:

```
<body >
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" >
     <div class="form-group" >
     <div class="col-sm-1">
     <a href="."  > <img src="Pictures/Design/בחזרה לאתר.png" height="100" width="100"/> </a>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
     <h2>הוספת ביקורת ל: <?php if(isset($_SESSION ['name'])){echo $_SESSION ['name'];} else {echo $gname;}?></label>
 </h2>
 </div>
</div>
<hr>

<div class="form-group">

     <div class="col-sm-12 " >

     <div class="col-sm-4 " align="right">
     <?php $val="uploads/guides/".$row['Picture'];?>
     <image src='<?php echo $val;?>' height="130px" width="100px">
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-7 " align="right">
     <div><label class=" control-label" ><?php if(isset($_SESSION ['name'])){echo $_SESSION ['name'];} else {echo $gname;}?></label><label class=" control-label" >&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp:שם המדריך</label></div>
<div><label class=" control-label" ><?php if(isset($_SESSION ['attraction'])){echo $_SESSION ['attraction'];} else {echo $gattraction;}?></label><label class=" control-label" >&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp:אטרקציה</label></div>
<div><label class=" control-label" ><?php if(isset($_SESSION ['email'])){echo $_SESSION ['email'];} else {echo $gemail;}?></label><label class=" control-label" >&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp:אימייל</label></div>
<div><label class=" control-label" ><?php if(isset($_SESSION ['phone'])){echo $_SESSION ['phone'];} else {echo $gphone;}?></label><label class=" control-label" >&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp:טלפון</label></div>
</div>                                
</div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="form-group">

     <div class="col-sm-12 " >
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6" align="right">
     <label class=" control-label" >שמך המלא</label>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-12">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder=""  />
     </div>

     </div>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">

     <div class="col-sm-12 " >
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6" align="right">
     <label class=" control-label" >מתי השתמשת בשירותי המדריך</label>
     </div>      

     <div class="col-sm-6 " align="right">
     <select class="form-control" name="year">
     <option value="בחר/י שנה">בחר/י שנה</option>                  
     <option value="2016">2016</option>
     <option value="2015">2015</option>
     <option value="2014">2014</option>
     <option value="2013">2013</option>
     <option value="2012">2012</option>
     <option value="2011">2011</option>
     <option value="2010">2010</option>
     <option value="2009">2009</option>
     </select>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-6 " align="right">

     <select class="form-control" name="month">
     <option value="בחר/י חודש">בחר/י חודש</option>  
     <option value="ינואר">ינואר</option>
     <option value="פברואר">פברואר</option>
     <option value="מרץ">מרץ</option>
     <option value="אפריל">אפריל</option>
     <option value="מאי">מאי</option>
     <option value="יוני">יוני</option>
     <option value="יולי">יולי</option>
     <option value="אוגוסט">אוגוסט</option>
     <option value="ספטמבר">ספטמבר</option>
     <option value="אוקטובר">אוקטובר</option>
     <option value="נובמבר">נובמבר</option>
     <option value="דצמבר">דצמבר</option>
     </select>
     </div>

     </div>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">

     <div class="col-sm-12 " >
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6" align="right">
     <label class=" control-label" >ציון 1-5</label>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-9 " align="right">
     <select class="form-control " name="rating">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
     </select>
     </div>

     </div>
     </div>  

     <div class="form-group">

     <div class="col-sm-12 " >
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6" align="right">
     <label class=" control-label" >כמה שילמת ומה זה כלל</label>
     </div>  
     <div class="col-sm-12">
     <textarea class="form-control" name="pay" cols="40" rows="2"></textarea>
     </div>

     </div>
     </div>


     <div class="form-group">

     <div class="col-sm-12 " >
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6" align="right">
     <label class=" control-label" >פרטו את חוויתכם עם המדריך בהרחבה</label>
     </div> 
     <div class="col-sm-12">
     <textarea class="form-control" name="exp" cols="40" rows="5" required></textarea>

     </div>

     </div>
     </div>


     <div class="form-group">

     <div class="col-sm-12 " >
     </div>                             
     </div>       
     <div class="form-group" >

     <div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-5"><button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary  btn-sm" name="addreview"  value="Submit Record">הוספת ביקורת</button></div>

     </div>

     <?php

     if(isset($_POST['addreview'])){ 
         $name = $_POST['name'];
         $name = str_replace("'","''",$name);
         $monthh = $_POST['month'];
         $yearr = $_POST['year'];
         $pay = $_POST['pay'];
         $pay = str_replace("'","''",$pay);
         $exp= $_POST['exp'];
         $exp = str_replace("'","''",$exp);
         $rating=$_POST['rating'];
         $query1="INSERT INTO review (ReviewerName,ServiceMonth,ServiceYear,Rating,Payment,Experience,Guide_ID) VALUES ";
         $query1.="('$name','$monthh','$yearr','$rating','$pay','$exp','$guideid')";
         $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query1);

         if($result){

             ?>
             <script type="text/javascript">
             window.location = "./review_added_successfully.php";
             </script>      
             <?php
         }
         else{
             echo "not submitted";
         }

     }   ?>              


</form>

</body>
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: It may be an encoding issue (ie: UTF-8 in the browser (or where ever you are coping from) and non-UTF in the DB as the default char set.

Comment: Can you reduce your question to a minimal example that demonstrates the problem? The other 100+ lines of code are probably not relevant.

Comment: "here's a recipe. it didn't work" doesn't really help us figure out the problem. if your cake doesn't work, then it's usually a good idea to say that you substituted road tar for eggs and sawdust for flour... that's somewhat useful information.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies.
This database was programmed for me, and the programmer cant be reached unfortunately, so i ned to deal with this with the little programming knowloadge that i have.
If i knew better to explain the problem i would, i was shooting for a maybe general problem that might occur here (such as if someone would say textarea object is not compatible with copy-paste, use X instead)

Comment: Ok i think now i can explain the problem better:
I have a mysqli database and i insert items into the databse using php forms.
My php is set to read utf8, my databse is set to utf8 and so is the collation of every specific table in the database.
but still when i input an item in english it is ok, but when i use hebrew (which is supposed to be ok with utf8) it shows me this error:

"Error description: Incorrect string value: '\xD7\x93\xD7\x92\xD7\x93...' for column 'Country' at row 1"

I know the problem is in the databes but i dont know where or how to fix it